# How would I declare a dynamic string as public?

Tags: java, android, tostring

I've created a `setOnFocusChangeListener` on an `EditText` so it will grab the string and add it to a `TextView` via `setText()`. However, I need a way to publicly and dynamically (in case they change the `EditText` again) use the `toString()` method so I can use it in another `setOnFocusListener`.

Heres my code, perhaps it will explain things in a less confusing way:

```
final TextView team1NameScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team1NameScore);
final EditText team1Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team1Name);

team1Name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            String team1NameString = team1Name.getText().toString();
            // Right here I need to make the above line public so I can use it later!
            if (!hasFocus) {
                team1NameScore.setText(team1NameString + "'s Score:");
            }
        }
    });
```

**(Read the comment on the 5th line)**

I have many focus listeners... I'd like to combine them into one preview that I generate for the user at the end (using `setText(textview1 + textview2 + team1Name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a field variable:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    public String team1NameString = "";
```

Then use it like any other variable:

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    team1NameString = team1Name.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare the string as an instance variable at the top of your class.

It cannot be a variable local to your parent method for the anonymous inner class, as then it would have to be final to be accessed by the listener, which means you can't alter its value. However, if you declare it as a global instance variable, your listener can access it, as can any other methods and listeners in your class.